# XP Start Menu Context Menu not opening folders

Tags: windows-xp, contextmenu, startmenu

I'm having an issue with the "Open"/"Open All Users", "Explore"/"Explore All Users" context menu options (right click menu) for shortcut folders (such as "Accessories") under the "All Programs" list on the "Start Menu" in Windows XP Home Edition.

Performing this action is supposed to open a My Computer/Windows Explorer window browsing the selected start menu folder. Normally, double clicking a start menu folder will also "Open" a My Computer window browsing the 
selected start menu folder.
Currently, these actions don't function and simply close the context menu/Start Menu without bringing up a My Computer/Windows Explorer window.

If I right click the "Start" button directly and select the corresponding options ("Open"/"Open All Users", "Explore"/"Explore All Users") a My Computer/Windows Explorer window is brought up as expected browsing "C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Start Menu" and "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu" respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused be third part programs.
Search in the windows registry for these keys:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers

Export all five keys (on the File Menu) (First two keys apply to files, 1st, 3rd to 5th apply to folders/drives).
Delete all two/five
Check if context menu works correctly (No need to reboot)

It is known that AVG anti virus adds a key that makes the context menu stop working.
MagicISO can be another cause.

In my experience I needed to remove MagicISO from the last key